# Data in measures paper

Tags: positional-astronomy

What do this data mean please?

http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1904AnOBN...8a...1N&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf

[image]

Comment: You should explain what it is that you do understand about the paper first, and demonstrate that you've put some effort into understanding it. This looks like a tiny crop from a random page from a 42 page paper, written in French, possibly a century ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Niesten 1904](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1904AnOBN...8a...1N/abstract) double star catalog explains its tables on [page 2](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1904AnOBN...8a...1N/0000015.000.html):

[image: Catalogue explanation in French]

The entry in question is for [δ Orionis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mintaka).

"A = 2" means the primary component was estimated at [apparent magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) 2.

"1879,12" is an observation date in fractional years, using a comma as a decimal point.

"163,0" and "161,7" are [position angles](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1904AnOBN...8a...1N/0000015.000.html) from the primary component to the secondary, in degrees counterclockwise from celestial north.
The * indicates an observation by Stuyvaert instead of Niesten.
"162,35" is an average of the two observations.

"en contact" means the separation between the two was smaller than the telescope's [angular resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution). Otherwise their separation would be given in arcseconds.

Comment: Thank you very much